# Get distance from Google Cloud Maps Directions API

Tags: python, google-maps, google-directions-api

I'm trying to get the distance between bus stops to get a rough estimate of when the bus is coming. I know there are apps and services that do this, but I want to do it myself.

I got the result object, but don't know how to get the distance. [Debug shows `directions_result` is a list with length of 0 (zero)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbasz.png)

(The code is from the [GC Maps Directions API Python Client documentation](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python#usagew).)

```
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
# GC Maps Directions API
coords_0 = '43.70721,-79.3955999'
coords_1 = '43.7077599,-79.39294'
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key=api_key)
# Request directions via public transit
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions(coords_0, coords_1, mode="driving", departure_time=now, avoid='tolls')
distance = directions_result.<what_im_trying_to_figure_out>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW, I removed the `# Geocoding an address` part from the sample code.

Comment: If you are looking for the math behind this and you can read JavaScript, maybe this article will help you: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: @John Hanley I'm not looking for the math, but the way to get the distance through the Python Client. Also, I want the driving distance, not the straight distance.

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your question as trying to duplicate what the `gmaps.directions` API does. Your example is not complete, therefore I don't know why the results are an empty array. Edit your question and include real code. Read this to understand how to post a question involve programming. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Post edited. Added import statementts and real coordnates tested on Google Maps (webapp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've ran your code and `directions_result` has length 1 for me. To get the total distance please try the code below:

```
# Import libraries
import googlemaps
from datetime import datetime
# Set coords
coords_0 = '43.70721,-79.3955999'
coords_1 = '43.7077599,-79.39294'
# Init client
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key="KEY")
# Request directions
now = datetime.now()
directions_result = gmaps.directions(coords_0, coords_1, mode="driving", departure_time=now, avoid='tolls')

# Get distance
distance = 0
legs = directions_result[0].get("legs")
for leg in legs:
    distance = distance + leg.get("distance").get("value")
print(distance) # 222 i.e. 0.2 km
```

Hope this helps you!